# Selecting a random value from unions

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I have the following query (I will omit the bindings to clarify things up):

```
(select * 
from advertisements 
where city_id is null and 
category_id is null order by RAND() asc limit 1) 

 union 

(select * 
from advertisements 
where city_id = ? and 
category_id is null) 

union 

(select * 
from advertisements where 
category_id = ? and 
city_id = ?) 

union

(select * 
from advertisements 
where city_id is null and 
category_id = ?)
```

How do I select a random row from the selected rows? I.e. there are 3 unions. If the query returns 5 rows, how should I modify this query so that it returns a random row from those 5?

Comment: Order the result by a random value and then take 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
select * from (select * from advertisements where city_id is null and category_id is null order by RAND() asc limit 1) union (select * from advertisements where city_id = ? and category_id is null) union (select * from advertisements where category_id = ? and city_id = ?) union (select * from advertisements where city_id is null and category_id = ?) as x
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

do a select again of the selected rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    (select * 
    from advertisements 
    where city_id is null and 
    category_id is null order by RAND() asc limit 1) 

     union 

    (select * 
    from advertisements 
    where city_id = ? and 
    category_id is null) 

    union 

    (select * 
    from advertisements where 
    category_id = ? and 
    city_id = ?) 

    union

    (select * 
    from advertisements 
    where city_id is null and 
    category_id = ?)
    ) AS d
ORDER BY RAND() ASC
LIMIT 1
```